# Unix: Why doesn't env A=42 echo ${A} work?

Tags: bash, echo, env

The `env` man page says that it'll set the specified environment variables and then run the specified command. Knowing that, I'd expect

```
env A=42 echo ${A}
```

to print `42`, but it shows nothing instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably because `${A}` is evaluated before echo is actually run

Comment: Yeah, that's why. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameter expansions occur before the shell runs the command. So if `A` currently has the value 3, the command line is first evaluated as

```
env A=42 echo 3
```

and *then* the shell identifies what command is to be run (`env`). At that point `env` constructs a new environment where `A` has the value 42, then runs the command `echo 3` in that environment.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `${A}` is evaluated *before* `echo` is executed. This means echo gets an argument with the value of `A` in the previous environment (no value...).

One solution is to pass the parameter as a literal string (single quote) to be expanded at a later stage along with `echo`:

```
user@host:~$ env A=42 bash -c 'echo ${A}'
42
```

Comment: Another solution : env E=42 printenv E

Comment: @M.Dogru thanks, didn't know about `printenv` (not an expert). More here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123473/what-is-the-difference-between-env-and-printenv